# Get max value from RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am having a difficult time getting the correct maximum value from a rich text box. I have tried using 3 different methods to find the max value and all work the same way. For this sample I am working with GPS Speed data. So I add the speeds 1 by 1 to the rich text box. The issue I am experiencing gives me a maximum speed value of 11.3 or 11.4 under certain scenarios.

For example, if the speed is greater than 12.0 it works fine. If the speed is below 11.0 it works fine. If the speed goes above (or starts above) 11.5 but then drops down below 11.5, the max reported will be one of these 11.3 or 11.4 numbers

It truly seems like my code believes 11.3 is the largest of numbers.

I tried Richtextbox.lines.Max(), i tried adding the data to a list, and also adding from the RTB to an array and using the methods below.

```
   Private Sub CheckMaxSpeed()
        Dim speed
        If MaxSpeedRTB.Text = "" Then
            MaxSpeedtxt.Text = "N/A"
            MaxSpeedtxt.Text = "N/A"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'speed = MaxSpeedRTB.Lines.Max()
            'Dim speedlist As List(Of String) = MaxSpeedRTB.Lines.ToList
            Dim myArr As String() = MaxSpeedRTB.Lines
            speed = myArr.Max()
            'speed = speedlist.Max
            speed *= 1.15078
            speed = Math.Round(speed, 1)
            If speed < 0.4 Then
                speed = "0.0"
            End If
            MaxSpeedtxt.Text = speed & " MPH"
            MaxSpeedRTB.Clear()
            MaxSpeedCom = False
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoking `Max` against `string` is a recipe for disaster.

Instead, try parse all lines as `Single` then invoke `Max` against it:

```
Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines

Dim values = New List(Of Single)

For Each line As String In lines
    Dim result As Single
    Dim tryParse = Single.TryParse(line, result)
    If tryParse Then
        values.Add(result)
    End If
Next

Dim max = values.Max()
```

Result:

```
For the following lines in RichTextBox:
11.1
11.123
Max = 11.123
```